# Create Schema for a specific Database in docker-entrypoint.sh

Tags: postgresql, psql

How do I create new Schema to a specific database in the shell script `docker-entrypoint.sh` of docker.

```
sudo -u postgres psql -c "ALTER user postgres WITH PASSWORD 'postgres'"
sudo -u postgres psql -c "CREATE DATABASE example;"
sudo -u postgres psql -c "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE example TO postgres;"
sudo -u postgres psql -c "CREATE SCHEMA production;"
sudo -u postgres psql -c "\dn"
```

In postgres there is no "use database" like mysql, so how can i specify this to the `example` database. At the moment the new Schema `production` goes to the `postgres` database in postgres as default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If not specified, [`psql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html) connects to a database with the same name as the user. If you do not want this, provide the database name it should connect to:

```
sudo -u postgres psql -d example -c "CREATE SCHEMA production;"
```

Comment: sorry i meant of course postgres. this is why they landed under postgres database. Thanks yout solution with '-d ' works.